# If $A \subset \mathbb{R^{n+m}}$ has Lebesgue measure zero then almost every section has measure zero.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Assume $A \subset \mathbb{R^{n+m}}$ has Lebesgue measure zero then prove for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$ the set

$$A_x=\{y\in \mathbb{R^m} ; (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^{n+m}} \}$$

is in Lebesgue $\sigma$-Algebra of $\mathbb{R^m}$ and has $m$-dimensional Lebesgue measure zero.

First I thought the Lebesgue $\sigma$-Algebra of $\mathbb{R^{m+n}}$ is the product of Lebesgue $\sigma$-Algebra of $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ and Lebesgue $\sigma$-Algebra of $\mathbb{R^{m}}$ and I proved the statement using this fact which I realised is wrong after reading this:
[Is the n-dim lebesgue measure the product of the lebesgue measure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679883/is-the-n-dim-lebesgue-measure-the-product-of-the-lebesgue-measure)

Now I am not sure how to prove this using definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^{n+m}$ is not the product of the Lebesgue measures on $\mathbb R^{n}$ and $\mathbb R^{m}$ but it is the completion of this product. You have to use the definition of completion of measures to prove this result. There exist Borel sets $B$ and $D$ and a set $C$ such that $A = B \cup C$, $C \subset D$ and both $B$ and $D$ have measure $0$. Now $A_x = B_x \cup C_x$ and $C_x \subset D_x$ from which it follows that $A_x$ has measure $0$ since $B_x$ and $D_x$ have measure $0$..

Comment: thanks for your solution. Now I understand that if $A_x$ is $\mathbb{R^m}$-Lebesgue measurable then by your argument it has measure zero but I don't know how to show for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$, $A_x$ is actually $\mathbb{R^m}$-Lebesgue measuarable.(why is $A_x$ in Lebesgue-$\sigma$-Algebra on $\mathbb{R^m}$ for almost every $x$?)

Comment: @user595419 $B_x$ is  Borel set so it is Lebesgue measurable. $C-x$ is Lebesgue measurable by completeness of Lebesgue measure. Hence $A_x=\B_x \cup C_x$ is Lebesgue measurable.